# How to update multiple rows in SQL server in one go without using temp table?

Tags: c#, sql-server

My application has one object called Client. Client have a property called status. I want to update the status of multiple clients based on user input.

Code:

```
public async Task UpdateStatus(List<ClientModel> clients, string modifyUserId)
    {
        var clientsToUpdate = clients.Select(x => new ClientViewModel { Id = x.Id, Status = x.StatusCd, ModifyDt = DateTime.UtcNow, MdfyUserId =  modifyUserId != null ? modifyUserId : string.Empty});
        var parameters = new List<IDbDataParameter>();
        foreach (var client in clientsToUpdate)
        {
           parameters.Add(dbManager.CreateParameter("@ClientId", 4, client.Id, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.InputOutput));
           parameters.Add(dbManager.CreateParameter("@ModifyDt", client.ModifyDt, DbType.DateTime));
           parameters.Add(dbManager.CreateParameter("@ModifyUserId", client.MdfyUserId, DbType.Int32));
           await dbManager.ExecuteNonQuery(Constants.StoredProcedures.UpdateClientStatus, CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters.ToArray());
           parameters.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Here in above code, call is going to database for every client which I want to improve. 
Is there any way to update multiple clients status in one go?

Comment: So is the user providing a list instead? Have you considered using a table-type parameter?

Comment: if "clients" is stemmed from a table then certainly from an SQL perspective this would work, although needing to call a stored procedure to update it would probably be a spanner in the works, but how to do it using views... dunno I havent used them

Comment: L A R N U* What don't you understand about my second question, I can't really be more clear; Have you though about using a table-type parameter? [Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)

Comment: @Larnu No, I haven't.

Comment: Then i suggest you do. :)